# Quantitative Lebesgue density theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $A \subset [0, 1]$ be a measurable set, and $\mathbf 1_A$ its indicator function, viewed as a function on $\mathbb R$. Define for each $\delta > 0$, the function $f_{A, \varepsilon}: \mathbb R \to [0, 1]$ given by

$$f_{A, \varepsilon} (x) = \sup_{r \leq \varepsilon} \frac{1}{2r} \int_{x-r}^{x+r} |\mathbf 1_A (y) - \mathbf 1_A (x)| \, dy.$$

By the [Lebesgue density theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_density_theorem), $f_{A, \varepsilon}$ converges pointwise a.e. to the zero function as $\varepsilon \to 0$, and hence in $L^1$ by the dominated convergence theorem.

**Question:** Do there exist some absolute constants $C, \delta > 0$ such that for any measurable subset $A$ of $[0, 1]$, and all $\varepsilon < \delta$, we have

$$\|f_{A, \varepsilon}\|_{L^1} < C\varepsilon?$$

**Remark:** The role of $\delta$ is not quite necessary, but it saves us the trouble of having to deal with the trivial case of large $\varepsilon$.

Comment: T.Tao in the Remark 2.2. in his notes https://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/247a.1.06f/notes3.pdf, mentions that one can construct an arbitrarily slow convergence.

Comment: @Thomas Kojar Indeed, at a point. However it may still be possible to get “on average” control.

Comment: I doubt it. I am trying to first understand it myself and see if we can modify it. But if you understand it first, please feel free to type it as answer, it would be cool to read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Split $[0,1]$ into $n$-dyadic intervals and consider the set of alternating intervals:

$$A_{n}\triangleq\Big[0,\frac{1}{2^{n}}\Big]\cup \Big[\frac{2}{2^{n}},\frac{3}{2^{n}}\Big]\cup\cdots\cup \Big[1-\frac{2}{2^{n}},1-\frac{1}{2^{n}}\Big]$$

and the function $f_{n}(x)=1_{A_{n}}(x)$. Then we have that for $x\in A_{n}$ and $r>2^{-n}$
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{1}{2r} &\int_{x-r}^{x+r} |\mathbf 1_A (y) - \mathbf 1_A (x)| \, dy\\
& = 1-\frac{|A_n \cap (x-r,x+r)|}{2r}=\frac{1}{2}.
\end{split}
$$
So for the $L^1$-norm and $\epsilon>2^{-n}$ we have the lower bound

$$\int_{A_{n}}f_{A,\epsilon}(x)dx=|A_{n}|\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{4}.$$

This example is from [T.Tao's notes](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2007/06/18/the-lebesgue-differentiation-theorem-and-the-szemeredi-regularity-lemma/). In the same notes, he does provide some interesting rate of convergence theorems.

Comment: Ah this simple example does work, very nice.